# How to run a useEffect on mount that references props with an empty dependency array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I only want useEffect to run a function on component mount, but the function references props and React gives a warning about adding the props to the dependency array - but if I do this, then it will no longer run on only component mount.

With classes:

```js
componentWillMount() {
    if (!this.props.variableInitialized) {
        this.props.dispatchPageFunction({ page: 'dashboard' })
        this.props.history.push('/')
    } else {
        this.props.dispatchPageFunction({ page: 'this_page' })
    }
}
```

Attempt with Hooks:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.variableInitialized) {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_PAGE', page: 'dashboard' }
        props.history.push('/')
    } else {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_PAGE', page: 'this_page' }
    }
}, [])
```

The hook way will complain about missing dependencies `dispatch` (the react-redux hook version of it, `useDispatch()`), `props.variableInitialized` and `props.history`, but if I add them, they'll no longer run exclusively on mount (and unmount in the hook way).

How do get the `useEffect` hook run in the same way as it did before with classes, without missing dependency warnings?

Comment: Try this `[dispatch]` as second argument to `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React hooks is still under development. It's possible that lint does not exactly has been accustomed with the uses of various hooks. According to [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

[image]

So, it's fine to disable lint for that case I think.

Answer (score 0):

try using the following syntax:

```
const [someString, setSomeString] = useState('init string');

const onMount = useCallback(
  () => {
    console.log(someString);
  }, 
  [state]
);

useEffect(onMount, []);
```

what happends here is that you use an outside function that is encapsulated in a useCallback. this syntax is ignored by eslint when it searches for dependencies.

the useCallback uses dependencies to update the function in case state changes. but the useEffect does not use any dependencies so that it does not run again ever after the mount.

practically making it as a onMount function

so in your case the code will look like this:

```
const onMount = useCallback(
    () => {
        if (!props.variableInitialized) {
            dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_PAGE', page: 'dashboard' }
            props.history.push('/')
        } else {
            dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_PAGE', page: 'this_page' }
        }
    }, 
    [dispatch, props.variableInitialized, props.history]
);

useEffect(onMount, [])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.variableInitialized) {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_PAGE', page: 'dashboard' }
        props.history.push('/')
    } else {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_PAGE', page: 'this_page' }
   } 
//eslint-disable-next-line },[])
```

**The comment(//eslint-disable-next-line) I added to the code will remove the complains you get for missing dependencies.**

Comment: Is this what I'm *supposed* to do though? I usually think that the linter gives such warnings for a good reasons, and there'd a way to accomplish this without disabling such warnings

Comment: In some cases, there is really no option because you can not some functions or variable as dependencies.

Comment: @platizin I believe, most times you better rethink concept behind `useEffect`to have more reliable code.see https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/